# How do I prevent MATLAB loop from crashing

Tags: matlab, optimization

I'm trying to do the following in MATLAB

call a loop - `for i=1:1000` and inside the loop I optimize a function using `fminunc`. Optimization is over a vector of parameters, one of which appears in a matrix in the function. Now it seems that `fminunc` calls an algorithm that inverts the matrix and then searches for a minimum. What happens is that when searching for a minimum a value that makes the matrix non-inverteble is given, and as MATLAB tries to invert the matrix, it spits an error and the loop stops. Is there a way I can adjust for this? Or perhaps less ideally, can I make it such that whenever this happens, MATLAB just ignores the optimization for that value of i and continues with `i+1`?

Comment: did you try using pinv, instead of inv?

Comment: thing is I don't invert the matrix in my code, the inversion is done by the algorithm for minunc.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need constraints then maybe?

Comment: I want to find the unconstrained minimum. Basically, if I could tell Matlab the following "Okay, I know that as you find the minimum your algorithm gives my parameter a value for which the matrix is not invertible, and you dont like that, but please, proceed and optimize the function for the remaining values of i in the loop for i=1:1000" then my problem would be solved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enclose the logic inside the loop in try/catch block.  Inside the catch block, do nothing, so it will just ignore the error and move to next loop iteration.

```
for i = 1:1000
   try
     ...
     ...
     ...
   catch
     % nothing..
   end
end
```

Comment: would have been my answer.  Good job.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

A `try - catch` block may be neccesary if you don't know whether something is going to work out or not. However, if you do know, then of course it is better not to try it at all:

```
for t = 1:1000
  if everythingIsGoingToBeAlright == 1
  % Do stuff
  end
end
```

Comment: Why does this have a downvote? It seems like the asker knows the reason of the error, so regardless of whether its practical in this specific case, it is usually a good idea to test for this rather than just try and let the `try catch` determine your program flow.